# Use non-standard floppy disk size with vmware player?

Tags: vmware-player

I'm testing very old distros and some of them have to create a non-standard floppy disk size (1722Ko).  It is the way the distrib is done.

could you tell if we can and possibly how to use a image of such a disk image with vmware player?

Cordially,

Comment: Try creating an `.iso` out of it and mounting it as a CD.

Comment: The problem is not using the live CD in itself, the problem occurs when the live CD try to write into the upper part of the disk.